# Why the image of any $A$-regular sequence under $f$ is a $B$-regular sequence, $f: A \to B$ is flat.

Tags: commutative-algebra, flatness, local-rings, regular-rings

The second answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7432/generalizing-miracle-flatness-matsumura-23-1-via-finite-tor-dimension) question claims: "If $f: A \rightarrow B$ is flat, then obviously the image of any $A$-regular sequence under $f$ is a $B$-regular sequence. This can be seen by tensoring the $A$-Koszul complex on an $A$-regular sequence, by $B$."

The quoted question talks about local Noetherian rings $(A,m_A)$ and $(B,m_B)$ with $f:A \rightarrow B$ a local homomorphism.

> **Questions:** Could one please explain that claim? Are there other ways to prove it? Is the claim talks about general commutative rings, not necessarily local Noetherian?

For a regular sequence of lengh one, for example, take a non-zero divisor $a \in A$, but, unless $B$ is an integral domain, I do not see why $f(a)$ should be a non-zero divisor in $B$ (perhaps this holds in a local homomorphism?).

(Perhaps [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594852/regularity-of-a-basis-over-a-local-ring) question is relevant, especially its second answer).

Thank you very much!

**Edit:** It seems that the claim is [Lemma 10.68.5](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AUH) (with $M=R$), in case we are dealing with local rings; I still wonder if the above quoted claim talked about a more general case.

Comment: Did you try to tensor the exact sequence $0\to A/(a_1,...,a_i)\stackrel{\cdot a_{i+1}}\to A/(a_1,...,a_i)$ by $B$?

Comment: @user26857, thank you. Truly, no. Just to make sure: $(A/(a_1,\ldots,a_i)) \otimes_A B \cong B/(f(a_1),\ldots,f(a_i))$?  So the claim is true for any flat $A \subseteq B$, with $A$ and $B$ not necessarily local Noetherian?

Comment: Correct! (Btw, I think this is proved in Matsumura, CRT)

Comment: Thank you again. The reference is also helpful; I now found this result in CRT, page 132, exercise 16.4, with the additional condition: $(A/(a_1,\ldots,a_n)) \otimes_A B \neq 0$ ($n$ is the length of the given $A$-sequence $a_1,\ldots,a_n$).

Comment: Of course we have to add such condition in order to don't permit the sequence to "explode" in B.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.